# Insert multiple values into one column and just one in other columns MySql Mamp

Tags: mysql, insert, mamp, insert-into, mamp-pro

[Bookings Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OR2Nw.png)

[Error For Insert on bookings table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3T65.png)

> [Current Insert command I have tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrRph.png)

Hi,

I am trying to insert into the bookings table bookings for a booking ID. I want to allow multiple time slots to be able to be inserted into the bookings table for one booking. I am having  little trouble with the syntax at the moment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are trying to insert a tuple with 8 values into your table with only 4 columns specified.  The error is self-explanatory, and the fix is to just provide values for the column names you specify in the insert.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I don't fully understand this, as i want them 5 different time slots to be stored in the time slots column for that individual row. The only logical way i see would be to name time slots 5 times so that the columns specified match up with the values inserted. This throws up. #1110 - Column 'time_slot' specified twice